# Problem with running metric_fu for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, metrics

I am trying to make this metric_fu get to work but I am getting a weird error.

```
braga@braga-laptop:~/prj/dummy_app$ rake metrics:all --trace
(in /home/braga/prj/dummy_app)
rake aborted!
RubyGem version error: chronic(0.6.2 not ~> 0.3.0)
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:812:in `report_activate_error'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:223:in `activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:258:in `activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:257:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:257:in `activate'
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:33:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/home/braga/prj/dummy_app/Rakefile:12
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2383:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2017:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2016:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2000:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

In Rakefile line 12 all I have done is given `require 'metric_fu'`. I tried uninstalling the chronic gem. Installed separate versions of 0.3.0 and 0.6.2 in all combinations. But still I cannot run the metrics. Any help would be much appreciated.

The rails version and ruby versions I use are

```
braga@braga-laptop:~/prj/dummy_app$ rails --version
Rails 2.3.14
braga@braga-laptop:~/prj/dummy_app$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-08-16 patchlevel 302) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: Yes.. I used --trace but that does not reveal much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a known problem. Metric_fu is very obtrusive, meaning it does not run out of the box for a rails project.  [Iain](https://github.com/iain/metrical) has created an excellent gem called metrical which wraps metric_fu and takes care of all the dependencies. And the most exciting feature is, it totally runs independent from the project.

To quickly get up and running look at this wonderful [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/252-metrics-metrics-metrics) by Ryan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the new maintainer of metric_fu and it should work now on ruby 1.9 without any problems. See configuration instructions at https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu which include how you can have metric_fu load external coverage output (e.g. using simplecov)

Also, it works from the command-line now. Now need to bundle it or run rake or metrical